# Communicating between classes set up in nib, in code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller, nib

A beginner's question:

If, in your nib, you have the File's Owner linked to the ViewController class, and you also have a NSObject-derived class, how do you communicate between the ViewController class and the NSObject class within code?

For instance, suppose ScientificCalculatorView.xib looks like this

```
File's Owner  (class: ScientificCalculatorViewController)
FirstResponder
View
Calculator  (an object that has been linked to the Calculator class)
```

Obviously, I'd want Calculator to be reusable, so it could be used with a NormalCalculatorViewController or something like that. So that UI and the calculator code are separate. Does Calculator even need to be in the nib?

It's a beginners question, but I'm just trying to get my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways (at least) to handle this:

1. Set up an outlet in your ScientificCalculatorViewController defined: 
   IBOutlet Calculator *calculator;  or something like that.  In IB connect that outlet to your Calculator object.  You will then be able to reference it in your ScientificCalculatorViewController.
2. In the - (void) viewDidLoad {} method, programmatically allocate and initialise a Calculator and set it to a property in your ScientificCalculatorViewController.  In this case, you can remove the object from your NIB.

Comment: How do you refer to the ScientificCalculatorViewController from within the Calculator object? (I know according to MVC principles you are not supposed to, but I am curious)

Comment: Sorry for being so long in getting back, trying to tidy up a beta for a client... 

You would have to tell the Calculator object about it.  Create a property within Calculator that is a ScientificCalculatorViewController * and set it from ScientifichCalculatorViewController in - (void) viewDidLoad {}

You could set this relationship up in IB as well, just make the property an IBOutlet and do the connecting.